# PLACEHOLDER - Forums - apiplatform.io

Tags: app, placeholder

I have a web application called [forums](https://forums.apiplatform.io) for which I intend to use stack exchange APIs. The forums application is a private community where the people in my organization post questions, reach out to others' posts and answer them. But for some queries, we wish to share them in Stackoverflow for answers from a larger group. To make this happen, I'm registering an application in the name, apiplatform.io in stack apps. This post is to let people know of the application that I registered and also to get write access.